# old fan/light for new

Tags: wiring, ceiling-fan, old-house

I changed out an old fan/light for new. The new one has a fancy control (no remote). I finished installing and went to hook up switch. Old wires present are two red and a white, no ground. The new switch has two black and a ground. I hooked up the two red and black and left the white as there was no white to hook up with. The fan is on but wont go off and the light wont go on. I can't get the fan to turn off unless I turn it off at the panel. Also the light on the switch to indicate power is not on. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: this is how I have the new switch set up and only fan on and can change speed or turn it off

[image]
[image]

[image]

sorry, can not turn light on or fan off

Comment: How many switches controlled this fan/light? Can you post photos of all boxes involved please?

Comment: Did you take pictures of the old setup before disconnecting everything?

Comment: it was just a normal swith. conected to the left side was two red cables , top and bottom and right side one white cable. Thanks

Comment: Your 1st and 2nd images are the same, did you have another one you'd intended to post?

Comment: Not related to your question, but I see copper in both red wires that are connected to the black wires.  You should not have exposed wire like that.   Shorten them up to ensure all copper is covered.

Comment: What is the second switch for?  Does it share any wires with the switch you are installing (or the one you uninstalled)?

Comment: the other switch is for an outside light. the wires are exposed as i dont see much point in finishing the job properly as it does not work. thanks